# Pass {% url %} to custom template tag in Django

Tags: django, django-templates

I'm developing a custom Django template tag that requires multiple arguments. One of those arguments is a URL. When I try to do this:

```
{% my_tag arg1 {% url "myview" %} arg3=5 %}
```

I get the following template syntax error: `Could not parse the remainder: '{%' from '{%'`

How can I pass a URL to a custom template?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Simple url tag supports assignment.

```
{% url 'myview' as my_url %}
{% my_tag arg1 my_url arg3=5 %}
```

Answer (score 3):

In case anyone really does want to get this working without having a lot of junk in thier templates I found that you can simply use [django.urls.reverse](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/urlresolvers/#reverse) in your [tag function](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/howto/custom-template-tags/#writing-custom-template-tags)

For example in your tag function:

```
from django.urls import reverse

@register.simple_tag
def my_tag(arg1, url, arg3 = None, *args, **kwargs):
    # resolve the url (you don't have to pass both args and kwargs, it's up to you.)
    resolved_url = reverse(url, None, args, kwargs)
    # do whatever you have to do
    pass
```

In your template simply pass the string that you would pass like `{% url 'myview' %}`:

```
{% my_tag arg1 'myview' arg3=5 %}
```

or

```
{% my_tag arg1 'myapp:myview' arg3=5 %}
```

by passing the args and/or kwargs along you can pass additional params to reverse (like a primary key for example).

```
{% # here the article.pk is passed to reverse # %}
{% my_tag arg1 'myapp:myview' arg3 article.pk %}
```