# How to pass an url tag in a custom template tag?

Tags: python, html, django, templates, django-templates

I'm learning Django building a small site, and I found that I have many templates where I list objects, each of them with a link to it.
I thought I could make a custom template tag, something like

```
{% object_list some %}
```

`some` is a dictionary `{'list': obj_list, 'link': link}` where `obj_list` is the list of objects I want to print out and `link` should some url structure that points to the item.

The template (called object_list.html) should look like

```
{% for object in object_list %}
    <li><a href="{% url myapp:object object.id %}">{{object.name}}</a></
{% endfor %}
```

Now, my problem is that I don't know what to do in the url. I want it to be flexible, such that 'myapp:object' is replaced by the argument 'link', for example, if the object type is User, then I use `{%url myapp:user user.id%}`.

It is possible to do this? How?

I tried [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22810636/pass-url-to-custom-template-tag-in-django), in the form

```
{% for object in object_list %}
    {% url 'link' as my_url %}
    <li><a href="{% url my_url object.id %}">{{object.name}}</a></li>
{% endfor %}
```

giving `'myapp:myobject'` as argument but it does not work. To be precise, in the template

```
{% load property_extras %}
{% object_list property_dict %}
```

where `property_dict` is my argument, and `templatetag/property_extras.py` is the file where the tag is saved, gives a NoReverseMatch error (if I use the normal template -without the custom tag- it works fine).

For more information, my template tag is

```
@register.inclusion_tag('properties/object_list.html')
def object_list(object_dict):
    print(object_dict['list'])
    print(object_dict['link'])
    return {
        'object_list': object_dict['list'],
        'link': object_dict['link'],
        }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe you can use

```
{% for object in object_list %}
    <li><a href="{{ object.get_absolute_url }}">{{object.name}}</a></li>
{% endfor %}
```

and remove the usage of `{% url %}` altogether. Defining the method `get_absolute_url` for your model is the recommended way of solving the problem according to the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/instances/#get-absolute-url).

Answer (score 2):

Using `{% url 'link' as my_url %}` doesn't work because you are using the literal string `'link'`, and you have not included the object id. Do you mean:

```
{% url link object.id as my_url %}
```

It's not clear why you save the result to `my_url`, because you don't use `my_url` anywhere. Maybe you want the next line to be:

```
<a href="{{ my_url }}">{{object.name}}</a></li>
```

However, I don't think you really need `as my_url` here. It silently swallows errors, which you probably don't want. It would be simpler to do:

```
<a href="{% url link object.id as my_url %}">{{object.name}}</a></li>
```